# Unable to locate object in object repository of uft

Tags: object, automation, hp-uft, uft14

I created object repository on day1 and all the tests were running fine.On day 2 when I tried to run the same scripts it was not running as on day 2 object was not identified as uft now created 2 test object with name "_2" added in the name of the test object.

For example earlier it was `MyApplication_1` then on next day it got changed to `My Application_2.Could you please help?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, how do `MyApplication_1` and `MyApplication_2` differ? Are you  recording or using learn? What technology are you using? Please try to give as much relevant information as possible to enable people to help you.

Comment: When you say "uft created 2 test objects" - did you re-record your test, update the OR or run a maintenance run?  -  What **actually** happened for this to occur?  -  the _2 is the on the object's **logical name**. UFT does this when you attempt to add a new object *it* thinks is unique (cannot identify as before)  .... Tell me more and i can guide you on a solution